# Does a non-negative integral multiplying a greater function greater than the original integral?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis

So let $f$, $g$, $h$ be multivariate functions on $\mathbb{R}^d$, and $\mathcal{Z}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^d$. Furthermore, we assume $g(z)\geq0$ for any $z$, and
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathcal{Z}}f(z)g(z)dz \geq 0.
\end{equation}
Note that we don't have any assumptions on the signs of $f(z)$!

If $h(z)\geq g(z)$ for any $z$, may we conclude that
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathcal{Z}}f(z)h(z)dz \geq \int_{\mathcal{Z}}f(z)g(z)dz?
\end{equation}

I believe it should be true, but proving it seems to be trickier than I expected because $f$ may be negative somewhere. I appreciate any insights.

Answer (score 1):

No

Take $f(x)=1$ on $[0,1/3)$ and $f(x)=-1$ on $[1/3,1]$ and $g(x)=1$ on $[0,1/3)$ and $g(x)=0$ on $[1/3,1]$

Then take $h(x)=1$ on $[0,1]$